# Какая временная сложность поиска в std::deque?

Tags: c++

Какая временная сложность поиска в std::deque?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо учитывать не только контейнер, но и алгоритм. Если рассматривать наихудший случай, то для поиска элемента необходимо обойти весь контейнер, т.е сложность O(n). Если элементы контейнера отсортированы, то  можно использовать бинарный поиск, он даст сложность O(ln(n)).